# Зачем тогда нужна тревога "не является ответом"?

Tags: поддержка, тревоги, блокировка-тревог

Я 12 лет на ресурсе. **На сайте 1052 дня, из них 576 подряд**. Я не злоупотребляю тревогами. Я всегда с пониманием отношусь к вопросам новичков, справедливо полагая, что каждый имеет право на ошибку. Понимаю, что к концу 90-х я, возможно, тоже был не особо адекватен, когда чем-то интересовался.

Есть такая тревога

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такой вопрос
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такой "ответ"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я помечаю тревогой такой "ответ", потому что это просто не является ответом (да и не только).

Вижу результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаю бан
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот реально я уже думаю уйти отсюда.
Это не единичный случай. Я просто стараюсь сделать мир лучше.
Вопрос: зачем тогда нужна тревога **не является ответом**?

Comment: Фишка в том, что даже если ответ ужасно плох, но все же хоть как-то релевантен, то он - ответ. (Например, "чему равно 2+2?" - "5" - это ответ, и "число между 3 и 7" - это тоже ответ, и т.п.). Можете его улучшить или влепить ему минус. Тревога "не ответ" предназначена для очевидных и вопиющих "не ответов".

Answer (score 6):

Это автоматическая блокировка. Система блокирует тревоги автоматически, если тревоги участника многократно отклоняются.

Но что вы хотели, чтобы модератор сделал с этим ответом? Да, он ужасен, но он ответ. А не например комментарий типа "у меня тоже такая проблема, что мне делать?" или что-то подобное, оформленное как ответ. Именно для подобного рода не-ответов предназначена данная тревога.

Другими словами, 1052 дня на сайте не дали вам полного понимания о том, как пользоваться тревогами. Всё что сделал модератор, это совершенно справедливо отклонил тревогу, больше ничего. Если бы это был я, то поступил бы точно так же.